# R - ggplotly set labels (rshiny)

Tags: r, shiny, label

I have a problem with ggplotly. I would like to change the labels of my x when the mouse is going on the plot. I have the following: y:number and I would like: People in middle class:number. See picture.

[image]

Here is my R code (within the server):

```
output$plotly1 <- renderPlotly({
 y<-glob_mid_class[input$years]
 p<-ggplot(mid_cl(), aes(x=Region, y=y)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggtitle("Global Middle Class") +
    xlab("Regions") + ylab("People in middle class") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ylim(0,3000)
 ggplotly(p)
})
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Why not change the name of your variable? `names(data)[1] = " People in middle class"`, whatever column stores your `y` variable

Comment: Yes actually, that can be a good idea!